# How to save individual residuals from an observed endogenous variable in a structural equation model?

Tags: residuals, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I am estimating a structural equation model in which two latent variables (with 4 indicators each) and the interaction between the two latent variables predict a single observed variable. I would like to save the individual residuals from the observed endogenous variable to use in further analyses. As far as I can tell, Mplus, the program I generally use, does not have a way to save the individual residuals.

- Is there a stats program that will allow me to save the residuals from an observed variable in a structural equation model?

Comment: I'd encourage anyone using Mplus to just ask the Muthéns themselves on the Mplus forums. Their customer service is amazing! Do let us know the resolution back here if you follow up on this particular question over there though!

Comment: Aparently someone found a trick, in the MPLUS [forum](http://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/11/1157.html?1411816972) is described.